# swapが使えない環境での運用

Tags: linux, centos

swap領域が使えないvps(osはcentos)でアプリケーションを動かしたいのですが、
すぐにメモリが足りなくなって落ちてしまいます。

ファイル管理のswapも試してみましたが、swaponコマンドを叩くと権限がない(rootで実行しても)と言われるのでお手上げ状態です。

このような環境で上手く運用する方法はないでしょうか。

ちなみにメモリは1Gで、アプリケーション自体はswapが使える環境で問題なく動きます。

Comment: スワップファイルで大丈夫そうですが権限不足で失敗ですか。何でしょうね…。どういう操作をしてどういうエラーが出たか省略せず質問に書いてもらえると回答が付きやすくなると思いますよ。

Answer (score 3):

おそらく、OpenVzやVirtuozzoなどのコンテナ型VPSを利用しているのだと思います。

これらのVPSでは単一のOS上で「他のユーザが見えない」機能が提供されているだけ、雑に言ってしまえば「すごいchroot機能が提供されている共用ホスティング」なので、OSそのものの設定を変更できるように設計されていません。また、他のユーザの影響を受ける可能性が高くなります。(その代わり、1台のハードウェアに多くのユーザを詰め込めるので安めに提供されています。)

このような状態でアプリケーションを安定して動作させるには、割り当てられたメモリの範囲内 (さらに言えば保証された範囲内) で動作するように開発・設定するしかありません。

求めている回答では無いかもしれませんが、完全仮想化・準仮想化で提供されているサービスに乗り換えるのが良いと思います。